# Tool for Android and iOS app test automation?

Tags: android, ios, testing, ui-automation

Is there any tool for testing Android and iOS apps? I know of Appium but that is used for web apps. 
I'm looking for something which I can use to automate UI testing just like selenium for web but on Android and iOS apps.

Also, the company I work for only provides me access to the various app builds and not the code itself so I want to be able to just test the downloaded apps.

cheers

Comment: Espresso tool for android automation UI Testing.

Comment: You can use jenkins for both android and iOS find here https://jenkins.io/doc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use appium for **webapps/native apps/hybrid apps for UI testing**

So one choice is **Appium + Binding language** of your choice e.g. Java,C#,Python etc

Other options would be to use **direct unit tests frameworks** for iOS / Android like

1. **Espresso** testing framework for Android apps
2. **Robot Framework** for Android apps [this is not a native framework]
3. **Instruments** or **XCUTest** for iOS apps

But if you choose native frameworks you have to learn them and you have to write different frameworks for both platform apps

So **recommended tool is Appium** as you can build single framework for both the platforms.

You do not require app code while doing automation using Appium.

The only requirement is

1. for **ios** you require **development builds**
2. for **android** in case of **hybrid app** you require **development builds**

For single framework you can use **@AndroidFindBy @IOSFindBy** annotations